# Possible to obtain NHunspell relevance score?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, nhunspell

I've implemented NHunspell to a program where right now it uses the word on a textbox and gives suggestions according to the word, in the future I will try and implement it to read a full .txt file.

The thing is I would like to play later with the suggested words and maybe replace the original word with the top suggestion automatically according to the relevance value, and list maybe the top 3 or top5 suggestions.
So the question is: **Is it possible to obtain a value of some kind from these suggested words?**

PS: NHunspell only accepts 1 word, is there a free or really cheap library that would let me spell check a sentence and give the suggestions according to all sentence and not word by word, being es-ES/pt-PT the priority dictionaries?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestions are ordered according to the relevance, that is all Hunspell provides.

Comment: I was hoping I could get them in some way.
What about filtering the total number of results? I mean giving only a maximum of 5.

Comment: What you need is a semantic analyzer (grammar checker), so you can use different suggestions and look if they make more "sense" in the whole sentence. László Németh, the creator of Hunspell is working on that with python. I think it is called lightproof